# How to filter images by IMAGE ID using docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### How do I filter images by their IMAGE ID using docker images?

When running the **`docker images`** command in the terminal I see a list of images, with 5 columns:

- REPOSITORY
- TAG
- IMAGE ID  ( <--- the thing which I want to filter by)
- CREATED
- SIZE

I noticed that a bunch of them have the same IMAGE ID, so I want to filter the list by that specific IMAGE ID. Now, before turning to an external solution like **`grep`** or **`awk`**, which does the job but does not display the table's headers, I was wondering if maybe it's possible to do so using one of the flags of **`docker images`**.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filter), you can only *filter* (using the `--filter` option) on:

- `dangling`
- `label`
- `before`
- `since`
- `reference`

None of those things let you filter by image id.

---

You can of course just use `awk`. On my system the image `4e50ce4113b1` has several names. If I run the following command:

```
docker image ls | awk '$3 == "4e50ce4113b1" {print}'
```

I see the following output:

```
127.0.0.1:10096/example/my-example-image         latest              4e50ce4113b1   2 weeks ago     986MB
127.0.0.1:10416/example/my-example-image         latest              4e50ce4113b1   2 weeks ago     986MB
127.0.0.1:10792/example/my-example-image         latest              4e50ce4113b1   2 weeks ago     986MB
```

---

Alternatively, you can output the image list in JSON and then filter it using `jq`:

```
docker image ls --format json | jq 'select(.ID == "4e50ce4113b1")'
```